# PyMySQL unable to execute multiple queries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

Using the latest version of PyMySQL(0.9.3) I am unable to execute a query string which has multiple SQL statements in it separated by a semicolon(;)

My python version is: Python 3.6.5

```
import pymysql # version 0.9.3
conn = {
    "host": "mysql_server_hostname",
    "password": "my_password",
    "port": <<port_no>>,
    "user": "my_username"
}

my_query_str = 'show databases;use random_existing_db;'
with pymysql.connect(**conn):
    cur.execute(query)
```

**Error returned: (1064, 'Multiple statements detected in a single query)**

Tried running the same query with  PyMySQL-0.7.11 and it works

Answer (score 19):

In pymysql version 0.8 onwards client flag is no longer set by default. For executing multiple statements one needs to pass
client_flag=CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS.

reference: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/v0.9.3/CHANGELOG#L66

Example of the fix below.

```
import pymysql
from pymysql.constants import CLIENT

conn = {
    "host": "mysql_server_hostname",
    "password": "my_password",
    "port": <<port_no>>,
    "user": "my_username",
    "client_flag": CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS
}

my_query_str = 'show databases;use random_existing_db;'
with pymysql.connect(**conn) as cur:
    cur.execute(my_query_str)
```

Comment: This is a great answer but the next logical question is how to I get the data returned for each of my queries? The answer is.
To get the results from the first query in the compound query, do `results_of_statement_1 = cur.fetchall()`, for subsequent queries, first check whether they are pending results by  `cur.nextset() == True`. Once this is `True`, you can get the results set by `results_of_statement_n = cur.fetchall()`. `cur.nextset()` will be `None`  when they are no more results to fetch.

Comment: I can't seem to find much documentation on this.  Anyone know 
 what the consequences of using client_flag=CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS are?

Comment: @PhilipPlachta can you clarify what type of consequences are you talking about ?

Comment: @RamShankarKumar Maybe it's a stupid question but I was wondering if there were any downsides to using that option. I ended up only passing that option in when I needed it b/c I couldn't find much about it.

Answer (score 3):

That's right, I used the `client_flag = CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS` parameter to take effect.